# The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Решил перенести `phpmyadmin` из одного поддомена на другой (на том же сайте). Добавил поддомен в CNAME, изменил адрес в вирт хостах `apache` и `nginx`, но теперь при заходе на новый поддомен `phpmyadmin` выдает ошибку:

> The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

При попытке зайти на сайт:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Ничего, кроме адреса вирт хостов в `apache/ngninx` я не менял и не трогал. До этого всё было в порядке.

Сервер - `Centos 7`, `php7`, `mariadb10`.

Comment: Значит в конфиге PHP для этого поддомена нет этого расширения. Если конфиг един для всех поддоменов то проверьте это, создав файл с <?php phpinfo(); ?> и проверьте есть ли там это расширение. Там же будет виден путь до php.ini если я не ошибаюсь.